# USB ports not responding in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb, xubuntu

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04 on an Asus X83V Laptop and a couple days ago, all my USB ports stopped responding, with neither my mouse nor flash drives or any usb devices responding. When I connect my phone to any USB port it does charge, but does not connect to my laptop. The same goes with my mouse, which lights up but doesn't respond.

My `lsusb` output with or without any devices connected is:

```
~$ lsusb  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Running `dmesg` gives me the following recurring output:

```
[125505.972198] hub 8-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1  
[125507.896116] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled  
[125509.816165] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled  
[125510.128196] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2  
[125512.048136] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled  
[125513.968164] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled  
[125514.152160] hub 8-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1  
[125516.076064] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled  
[125517.996146] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled  
[125518.308109] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2  
[125520.228063] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled  
[125522.148148] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled  
[125522.332195] hub 8-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1  
[125522.644068] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2  
[125526.168137] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled  
[125526.480203] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2  
[125526.720130] usb 8-1: new full-speed USB device number 51 using uhci_hcd  
[125527.128105] usb 8-1: device not accepting address 51, error -71  
[125527.240157] usb 8-1: new full-speed USB device number 52 using uhci_hcd  
[125527.648158] usb 8-1: device not accepting address 52, error -71  
[125527.760051] usb 8-1: new full-speed USB device number 53 using uhci_hcd  
[125527.824202] hub 8-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1  
[125529.748164] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled  
[125531.668058] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled  
[125531.980148] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2  
[125532.164198] hub 8-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1  
[125534.084123] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled  
[125536.004170] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled  
[125536.316167] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2  
[125538.240057] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled  
[125540.160128] hub 2-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled  
[125540.400157] usb 8-1: new full-speed USB device number 55 using uhci_hcd  
[125540.808153] usb 8-1: device not accepting address 55, error -71
```

I'm running kernel 3.2.0-34-generic and have tried updating it to 3.6 but to no avail. SOS?

Comment: I an getting similar output to you on demsg, but I know my onboard controller is bad.  Are you certain yours is working normally?